# A resource failed to call close with new project created using Android studio Flamingo

Tags: android, memory-leaks

After creating a new project with empty activity template and just run the app, I notice there is a warning "a resource failed to call close" in logcat. This is a bug isn't it?

```
ProfileInstaller        com.hoan.baseapplication             D  Installing profile for com.hoan.baseapplication


System                  com.hoan.baseapplication             W  A resource failed to call close.
```

Comment: I see that the `activity` is empty. Do you have any other code in the application?

Comment: No just the whatever code the studio template created. That is the second template when you create a new project.